# Pass by reference to a recursive function

Tags: c, function, recursion, pass-by-reference

```
#include <stdio.h>

void word(char a[100], int i, int *max, int *c)
{
    printf("%d  %d", max , c);
    int length = 0;
    while (i < strlen(a) && a[i] != ' ')
    {
        length++;
        //printf("%c\n", a[i]);
        i++;
    }
    if (a[i] == ' ' && i < strlen(a))
    {
        c++;
        if (length > max)
            max = length;
        //printf("%d\n%d", max, c);    
        word(a, i + 1, max, c);
    }
}

void main()
{
    char a[100];
    int max = 0, j, i = 0, c = 0;
    scanf("%[^\n]s", &a);
    word(a, 0, &max, &c);
    printf("%d\n%d", c, max);
}
```

**GIVEN PROBLEM**: *Given a String with spaces, write an algorithm and a C program to count the number of words in it and length of the longest word. For example, if the input string is ‘I love programming’ then the number of words is three and length of the longest string is 11.*

I am facing problem while passing the variables `max` and `c` by reference in the recursive function `word()`. The variables are not being passed properly. i wish the variables to be passed by reference recursively so as to update their value with each recursive call. I am a newbie to stackoverflow, so please correct me wherever I have made mistakes.

Comment: `printf("%d  %d", max , c);`-->`printf("%d  %d", *max , *c);`

Comment: Pump up the compiler's warning level, recompile, read and understand the warnings, fix the code, start over.

Answer (score 1):

Using `*` means you're passing a pointer, not a reference (C doesn't have references). You should probably read over some info pages like [**this really clear one**](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/141834/how-is-a-java-reference-different-from-a-c-pointer) and [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Pointers_and_arrays) to familiarise yourself with the differences between the two.

Doing eg. `max = length` is then changing the address that's pointed to by `max`, rather than changing the value at that address. You mean `*max = length`, where you're dereferencing the pointer to get the value at the address it points to, then assigning to that value, which updates the "referenced" variable as you intend. Given this, `printf("%d %d", max , c)` doesn't print the values - you need some more `*`'s.

Similarly, `c++` advances the address pointed to be `c` by one, it doesn't increment the integer pointed to by `c` (to do that, you should use `(*c)++`).

---

You should always compile with at least `-Wall`, so the compiler gives you full warnings. In this case, you'll get multiple warnings about invalid pointer assignments, including where they occur so you can fix them more easily.

Answer (score 1):

We beginners should help each other.

Here you are.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

size_t word( const char *s, size_t *max_word )
{
    size_t count = 0;

    s = s + strspn( s, " \t" );
    if ( *s )
    {
        ++count;

        size_t n = strcspn( s, " \t" );

        if ( *max_word < n ) *max_word = n;

        count += word( s + n, max_word );
    }

    return count;
}

int main(void) 
{
    const char *s = "I like programming using C";
    size_t max_word = 0;
    size_t n = word( s, &max_word );

    printf( "Number of words in the string is %zu\n"
            "The length of the maximum word is %zu\n ",
            n, max_word );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Number of words in the string is 5
The length of the maximum word is 11
```

As for your code then for starters according to the C Standard the function `main` without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

The function declaration

```
void word(char a[100], int i, int *max, int *c);
```

is too complicated. If you can return something useful from a function you should return it.

The declaration of the first parameter specifying the size of the array does not make great sense because the parameter is adjusted to pointer.

As the string is not changed in the function it should be declared with the qualifier `const`.

The second parameter is redundant because character arrays that contain strings have sentinel value equal to `'\0'`. And at least it should have the type `size_t`.

Take into account that the symbol `'\t'` also serves as a word separator.

The initial string and any substring can start with spaces. However your function ignores this fact.

The first and second while loops can execute never and in this case the function returns an invalid values for the count of words and for the maximum length.

Moreover this statement

```
c++;
```

does not make sense because it increases the pointer instead of increasing the value pointed to by the pointer.

This statement

```
max = length;
```

also changes the pointer itself instead of changing the value pointed to by the pointer.